# Why is Git using the wrong ssh key?

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-keys

On my Windows PC, I am using Pageant and putty to login to a remote ubuntu with my ssh key (e.g. named *my-key*).

On ubuntu I would like to fetch code from a remote git repository via ssh. There is a local ssh key in *~/.ssh* for that user (e.g. named *coders-key*) which is supposed to be used with the remote git repository.

For some reason, git is using the key I used to login to the ubuntu (*my-key*) instead of using the key from the *~/.ssh* folder.

How can I make git use the ssh key from *~/.ssh*?

Comment: You can try using ssh-add: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/coders-key` on your Ubuntu server

Comment: coders-key is already on the ubuntu server. but git is using my-key instead for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is SSH Agent Forwarding (https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/).